# Line breaks in a string

Tags: javascript, string

Script #1:

```
<textarea></textarea>

$('textarea').each(function() {
  var $placeholder = "First line\nSecond one";
  console.log('[function] shikamo__edit_placholder, data-placeholder: ' + $placeholder);

  $(this).attr('value', $placeholder);
  $(this).focus(function(){
      if($(this).val() == $placeholder){
          // reset the value only if it equals the initial one    
          $(this).attr('value', '');
      }
  });
  $(this).blur(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
          $(this).attr('value', $placeholder);
      }    
  });
  // remove the focus, if it is on by default
  $(this).blur();
});
```

returns

```
<textarea>First line
Second one</textarea>
```

---

Script #2:

```
<textarea data-placeholder="First line\nSecond one"></textarea>

$('textarea').each(function() {
  var $placeholder = $(this).attr('data-placeholder');
  console.log('[function] shikamo__edit_placholder, data-placeholder: ' + $placeholder);

  $(this).attr('value', $placeholder);
  $(this).focus(function(){
      if($(this).val() == $placeholder){
          // reset the value only if it equals the initial one    
          $(this).attr('value', '');
      }
  });
  $(this).blur(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
          $(this).attr('value', $placeholder);
      }    
  });
  // remove the focus, if it is on by default
  $(this).blur();
});
```

returns

```
<textarea data-placeholder="First line\nSecond one">First line\nSecond one</textarea>
```

---

How can I get the same result with a line break

```
<textarea data-placeholder="First line\nSecond one">First line
Second one</textarea>
```

from Script #2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using @Ishita's answer

```
$(this).attr('value', ($placeholder.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")));
```

**EDIT**

it's because when you read a property from placeholder attribute it's seen not as a line break but as a regular `\n` string. if you change that string back into line break, you are at home.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<br/> instead of /n
```

Or if you are rendering a string,

```
replace /n with <br/>
// this is code for string replacement
replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

Basically, write this code

```
  $(this).attr('value', ($placeholder.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")));
```